# Ignore last characters regex

Tags: php, regex

I created this regex expression but when I run it it recognizes the last two characters in my code. The " and the > are left but I dont want those.

Also will this regex expression work in php with preg_replace?

```
(?!(src)=)(ht|tp)(\w+.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/kU7pF1/4

Comment: In PHP, you'd better use DOMDocument to collect links from `href`s. No need using a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
(?!(src)=)(ht|tp)(.+?)(?=">)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU7pF1/7)**

or this

```
(?!(src)=)(ht|tp)([^">]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU7pF1/5)**

Yes it will work with `preg_replace` as long as the URL matches with regex

Comment: Is there a way to make it only recognize this tag: <source src="http://www.google.com">

Comment: Yes perfect, I didn't think of that, thanks for your help

Comment: @KryometricGaming as suggested, avoid parsing HTML with regex..there are tools that can do that